# SaveAs won't accept strings that contain "." in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code in order to add a new workbook,save and name the workbook (based on a date which is located in a certain cell in the sheet).

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbName As String
wbName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M145").value 


    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(wbName)
    If fName = False Then
        MsgBox "Publish couldn't be completed since you didn't choose where to save the file."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        wb.SaveAs (fName)
    End If
```

But it seems that whenever cell "M145" contains dots (".")  as in "31.3.16", my file name doesn't appear in the SaveAs prompt and I see a blank line without
any error message.

I don't think that this has anything to do with it, but my sheet is right-to-left. Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try `cstr` on `wbname`?

Comment: Are you certain? Use debugger to verify the value assigned in `wbName` is what you think it is.

Comment: This works for me using right-to-left, or left-to-right.

Comment: yeah.. used both the debugger and msgbox, both say wbName eqaules to "30.3.16"

Comment: Try `wbName = """" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M145").value  & """"`?

Comment: Nope.. still doesn't work

Comment: I suggest an alternative answer, but also curious what happens if you hard-code it: `fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("31.3.16")` -- if *that* works, then maybe @Jeeped answer below will help, though you're casting to a `String` type already and that is not raising any error...

Comment: i found this, by trying different things and reading microsoft help : `?Application.GetSaveAsFilename("31","MyFormat (*.3.16),*.3.16")` in the immediate window.  So you can adapt it by adding a `If Instr(wbName,".")>0 then ...`

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks you for your effort. I am not sure I understood the method that you had suggested.  Instr(wbName,".")>0 will always return True since it always refers to a cell that contains a date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm not able to replicate the error, perhaps you will have better luck with a `FileDialog` object:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbName As String
Dim fdlg As FileDialog

wbName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M145").value 

Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fdlg
    .InitialFileName = wbName
    .Show
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    On Error Resume Next 'Suppress any errors due to invalid filename, etc.
    wb.SaveAs(fdlg.SelectedItems(1))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then  
        MsgBox "Publish couldn't be completed since you didn't choose where to save the file."
        wb.Close False  'Get rid of the workbook since it's not being saved
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 'Resume normal error handling
End With
```

Comment: You're welcome. Still curious to know what happens if you hardcode it as: `fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("31.3.16")`?

Answer (score 2):

There two things going on here.

First, M145 likely contains a date that has been given a format mask of `dd\.mm\.yy`. To get that displayed value out of the cell and into a variable you need the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx), not the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx).

Second, the default filetype for the [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx) is `*.*` which means that it is going to accept the `.yy` as the file extension. You need to limit the available file extensions to Excel file types.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbName As String, fName As Variant  'variant in case user clicks Cancel

wbName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M145").Text

With Application
    fName = .GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=wbName, _
                               FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
                                           "Macro Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
                                           "Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb")
End With
```

That gets you past the problems with your filename selection. However, the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) should also provide the correct [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).

```
Select Case fName
    Case False
        'user clicked Cancel or Close (×)
        Debug.Print fName
    Case Else
        With Workbooks.Add
            Select Case Right(fName, 5)
                Case ".xlsx"
                    .SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                Case ".xlsm"
                    .SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
                Case ".xlsb"
                    .SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
                Case Else
                    'there really shouldn't be a case else
            End Select
        End With
End Select
```

Comment: Good stuff but OP is casting to a `String` type already, and has verified via debugger that `wbName` contains string, so I'm not sure the Date/Long data type would cause this behavior with the `InitialFileName`

Comment: The way the fName is treated will depend somewhat on what the computer's short date is set to display but I feel that the .Text property is more universal than the .Value because it is giving you what the worksheet shows, not the formula bar. Additionally, my experiments were chopping off the .yy when used with a `*.*` file filter.

Comment: I actually tried to use .Text and it gave me the same results

Comment: @Sergey - ... and you specified one or more of the workbook file extension filters? e.g **not** `*.*`

Comment: I am quite new to VBA so I don't exactly understand what your filefilter does, but I got the same result when I ran your code.. still no file name in the SaveAs prompt..