# VBA downloading a file from a URL where the file name keeps changing daily

Tags: excel, url, vba

Can someone help me as I'm pulling my hair out. I'm trying to download a file from a site & copy it to another location. If I use the actual file name commented out below it works. Sadly the file name changes every day & I have accounted for that in cell B1 (01 04 2016). Anyway I'm getting an error of 'Compile error: Constant expression required' and  highlighting the first '&'. Does anyone have any ideas that might help?

{

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
                                           "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                                           ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
                                           ByVal szFileName As String, _
                                           ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                                           ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


`enter code here`Sub DownloadFileFromWeb()
Dim i As Integer

    Const strUrl As String = "https://test.com/sites/Field Completions Reported " & Range("B1") & ".xlsb"
    '"https://test.com/sites/Field Completions Reported 01 04 2016.xlsb"

    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim returnValue As Long

    strSavePath = "C:\Users\1234\Desktop\Field Completions Reported.xlsb"
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

}

Comment: `Const strUrl As String = "https://test.com/sites/Field Completions Reported " & Range("B1") & ".xlsb"`. As the compiler said, constant required, `Range()` not allowed

Comment: consider dim it as string. then you can use `range()` to assign to it

Comment: See [SaveAs won't accpet strings that contain “.” in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320580/saveas-wont-accpet-strings-that-contain-in-excel-vba/36320966#36320966) about saveas and dates from ranges.

Comment: I thought you had it but I had now joy with that. I'm really struggling!!!

Comment: if I do a check with a MsgBox """https://test.com/sites/test/Field Completions Reported " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") & ".xlsb""" then the format appears correct.

Comment: One moment. posting an answer :)

Comment: The formula in cell B1 is 
=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd")&" "&TEXT(TODAY(),"mm")&" "&YEAR(TODAY())

Comment: @KSSheon: My Apologies. I just noticed that you have already suggested what I posted as an answer. I would recommend that you post that as an answer and then I will delete mine.

Comment: @SiddharthRout no problems. i came here to learn rather than to focus on giving advice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Compile error: Constant expression required

You can't use `Const` with a `Variable`. When you use `Const` then pass something which doesn't change. For example

```
Const a = "Sid" '<~~~ This will work
Const a = "Sid" & i '<~~ This will not work. i is a variable
Const a = "Sid" & Range("A1").Value  '<~~ This will not work. Range("A1") is a variable
```

Change your code to this

```
Dim strUrl As String

'"https://test.com/sites/Field Completions Reported 01 04 2016.xlsb"
strUrl = "https://test.com/sites/Field Completions Reported " & _
         Range("B1").Value & ".xlsb"
```

Comment: I just realised that @KSSheon already suggested this in the comments above. Please do not accept this answer. Let him reply to this and then you can accept his answer :)