# How do I save a workbook with a specific name to a specific folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner.

I want to save a copy of the active workbook with a different name to a specific folder.
The name would look like this Dailycheck Nov 11 2022.xlsm

Can someone please help me?

Thank you

```
Sub BackupWorkbook()

'Step 1: Create a Backup of a Workbook with Current Date in the Same folder

     ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
            FileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & _
            Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & " " & _
            ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

I copied the above code but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: What's the name of the file you're saving a backup for in that example?  Where exactly is the destination folder located?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA Saving File in Designated Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636460/excel-vba-saving-file-in-designated-location)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Save a Copy of `ThisWorkbook`

- [`Workbook.SaveCopyAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) (Microsoft)
- The following saves a copy of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) to the same folder with a specific name also containing today's formatted date.

```vb
Sub SaveCopyOfMe()

    ' Set the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Build the folder path.
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    ' Build the base name (no file extension).
    Dim BaseName As String: BaseName = "DailyCheck " _
        & StrConv(Format(Date, "mmm dd yyyy"), vbProperCase)
    ' If you want English, no matter your locale, instead use:
    'Dim BaseName As String: BaseName = "DailyCheck " _
        & StrConv(WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "mmm dd yyyy"), vbProperCase)
    ' Note that VBA's 'Date' is the equivalent of Excel's 'TODAY()'.
    
    ' Build the file extension.
    Dim wbName As String: wbName = wb.Name
    Dim FileExtension As String
    FileExtension = "." & Right(wbName, Len(wbName) - InStrRev(wbName, "."))
    ' Or just:
    'FileExtension = Right(wbName, Len(wbName) - InStrRev(wbName, ".") + 1)
    
    ' Build the file path.
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & BaseName & FileExtension

    ' Save a copy using 'SaveCopyAs':
    '   - saves in the same file format (i.e. needs the same file extension)
    '   - overwrites without confirmation
    wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FilePath

End Sub
```